# Easiest way to make cash

Tags: dont-get-fired

I'm at the manager position but can't seem to make the promotion. My skills are easily coping with work and assigning slaves. But my promo chance is really low and I wanna buy the $32000 upgrade. Part time jobs not as helpful anymore. Lottery is negligible. Is there any way to get some money quick? Or at least big? And no, I will not buy money ingame.

Answer (score 2):

The scary tax return challenge gives you 3000 if you succeed. Just keep changing your time on your phone

Answer (score 0):

There are three main sources of money in the game:

1. Side jobs ($300-$600 every 5 minutes);
2. Challenges ($50-$3000 every 60 minutes + 1 extra each time you get fired);
3. Getting fired ($0-$700000 depending on position).

The best source of income is, then, to get fired, take the challenge at the next opportunity, and repeat. Supplement with side jobs.